# Saving multiple structures into a binary file (C)

Tags: c, function, file-io, struct

I'm writing down a function that should save 3 structures (2 of them are arrays of structs) in a binary file. Here's my function:

```
void saveFile(Struct1 *s1, Struct2 *s2, Struct3 s3) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("save.bin", "w+b");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Save failed.\n");
    }

    fwrite(s1, sizeof(Struct1), struct3.nElements, fp);
    fwrite(s2, sizeof(Struct2), NELEMENTS, fp);
    fwrite(&s3, sizeof(Struct3), 1, fp);

    printf("Save done.\n");
}
```

`s1` have `struct3.nElements`, `s2` have `NELEMENTS` (that's a constant) and `s3` is just one struct and not an array. When I try to open the save.bin with HexEditor it gives very different results from the ones I was expecting, I'm wondering if I used correctly the `fwrite` function, especially for array of structs.

Comment: Which results did you get with the hex editor, which results did you expect and what did you write into your file. You have to share that information with us if you want to get answers. Read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MichaelWalz when I use HexEditor I see random characters, some correct fields of 'struct2' and also paths of some programs like Visual Studio. I am expecting to see the right values of structures, obviously.

Comment: Show how you call `saveFile`. The problem is probably there. And show the declarations of `struct1`, `struct2` and `struct3`.

Comment: The layout of a structure and its padding bytes etc are pretty much implementation defined. It is not a good practice to write whole structs like that.

Comment: Also show the reading function.  Is the reading done on the same computer with the same compiler as the writing?

Comment: Should `
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Save failed.\n");
    }` bail out?

Comment: Why no `fclose()`?  Oversight or intentional?

Comment: @Antti Haapala  Disagree about " not a good practice to write whole structs".  That is what `fwrite()` is for.  I would find interesting what reasons you have for ever using `fread/fwrite`.

Answer (score 2):

There are small issues with you function that might cause problems:

- you define the function as taking `s3` by value. Why not pass a pointer to the third `struct`? Is the `saveFile` function properly declared before the calling code? Are you sure the calling code passes the `struct` by value?
- You forget to close the stream.  The handle gets lost, and the contents is not flushed to disk until the program exits.
- You open the file in `"w+b"` mode: write with read.  It is correct to use binary mode, but unnecessary to add the `+` for read.  Just use `"wb"`.
- If `fopen` fails, you output a diagnostic message, but you do not return from the function.  You will invoke undefined behavior when trying to write to a `NULL` stream pointer.

Regarding your question, the dump of the file does not correspond to what you expect... give us more information, such as the definitions of the different structures and the hex dump. Here are some ideas:

- Some of the fields in the structures might need a specific aligned and thus be separated from the previous field by padding bytes.  The values of those padding bytes is not necessarily `0`: if the structures are in automatic storage or allocated with `malloc`, their initial state is undefined and can change as a side effect of storing other fields.
- Integers can have different sizes and be stored in little endian or big endian order in the file, depending on the specific architecture your program is compiled for.  For this reason, values stored by your program should only be read back with the appropriate, but reasonably similar code, running on the same architecture and OS.
- If your structures contain pointers, you cannot really make sense from the values stored in the output file.

Comment: "You forget to close the stream. The handle gets lost, and the contents is not flushed to disk until the program exits." is the best suspect. AFAIK, the data does not even need to be written if a close/flush is missing.

Comment: @chux: C11 7.22.4.4: the `exit` function: *Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all open streams are
closed, and all files created by the tmpfile function are removed.*

Comment: True, yet code is not posted how things ended.  Consider `abort  _Exit`. "open streams are closed, or temporary files are removed is implementation-defined"  OP's reflectance to post a complete MCVE with  structures, data read and data observed all  contribute to unnecessary challenges in answering this post.